# How can I find out the token balance of some address?

Tags: solidity, tokens

How can I find out the token balance of some address using Solidity?

For example, I have the address of another person, and I need to know the number of tokens on his account.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 2 ways using https://etherscan.io/ :

1. Navigate to https://etherscan.io/ . Enter the account in the search box on the top right, the click **Go**. If there are tokens associated with the account, you will see the **Token Tracker** dropdow. Clicking this will show you the number of tokens owned by the account. For example: https://etherscan.io/address/0xc49cee55a099349bc5a67a6a454dbad3833e7b14 :

[image]

2. If you know the token, navigate to https://etherscan.io/ . Select the menu Token -> View Tokens. Then select the token in the list. In this example, we will look at Golem. Enter the address of interest in the **Filter By Address field** and click **Apply**. The following screen shows the details for the same address in the example above:

[image]

---

#### Update Responding To The More Specific Question On Getting The Balance Using Solidity

Here is an example using GNT, where I got the ABI from the GNT contract details at [0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d#code):

```
> var gntABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"golemFactory","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_master","type":"address"}],"name":"setMigrationMaster","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"migrate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"finalize","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"refund","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"migrationMaster","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tokenCreationCap","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_agent","type":"address"}],"name":"setMigrationAgent","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"migrationAgent","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"fundingEndBlock","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalMigrated","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tokenCreationMin","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"funding","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"tokenCreationRate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"fundingStartBlock","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"create","outputs":[],"payable":true,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_golemFactory","type":"address"},{"name":"_migrationMaster","type":"address"},{"name":"_fundingStartBlock","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_fundingEndBlock","type":"uint256"}],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Migrate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Refund","type":"event"}];
undefined
> var gntAddress = "0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d";
undefined
> var address = "0xc49cee55a099349bc5a67a6a454dbad3833e7b14"; // Address in examples above
undefined
> var gntContract = eth.contract(gntABI).at(gntAddress);
undefined
> var balance = gntContract.balanceOf(address).div(1e18);
undefined
> balance
23771.112437704491608715
```

---

#### Update With Script To Find GNT Balances For Multiple Accounts

The `getGNTBalances` script from https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/tree/master/scripts will produce the following type of output:

```
  #     Account                                                             GNT                        ETH
------- ------------------------------------------ ---------------------------- --------------------------
  0     0x4319c142f7b6cd722fc3a49289b8a22a7a51ca1e 180000000.000000000000000000       0.000000000000000000
  1     0x168ae36b4386cea14475faa41498a0ea63c67dd7 100000999.999999991611392000   11717.218877544008288507
  2     0xd39379d7887c6a9ebd01007e2b96efc774652047  57459993.000000000000000000  106160.984854218882216845
------- ------------------------------------------ ---------------------------- --------------------------
  3     Total                                      337460992.999999991611392000  117878.203731762890505352
```

Just change the address in the script to any ERC20 compliant token to view the balances for that token.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I find the code on Solidity. For example there balanseOf function for ether, but I need balans tokens.

Comment: Updated answer with an example in Solidity

Answer (score 5):

[Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) exposes an [API](https://etherscan.io/apis#tokens) which can be used to find the balance instead.

> Get ERC20-Token Account Balance for TokenContractAddress

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x57d90b64a1a57749b0f932f1a3395792e12e7055&address=0xe04f27eb70e025b78871a2ad7eabe85e61212761&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

Where address is the person's address.

And contractaddress is the token address in this case `Elcoin`

Comment: Is there anyway to list holders of a specified ERC20 contract?

Answer (score 0):

With RPC:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"to": "0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0", "data":"0x70a082310000000000000000000000000b88516a6d22bf8e0d3657effbd41577c5fd4cb7"}, "latest"],"id":67}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:8545/
```

For details refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998988/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

It's more complicated if you want to query a token you deployed for testing. You can either:

1. Use the hex version of the `balanceOf(address)` of the
   ERC20-compliant tokens in a js file.
2. Recompile your sol file with `solc` or `truffle`, either programmatically or from the terminal, and then load your `*.abi` files using `web3.eth.contract(ABI).at(address);`
3. RPC with etherscan.io, as @garg10may explained above

I personally chose 1, you can find some sample code [here](https://github.com/ThatOtherZach/Web3-by-Example/wiki/Get-Token-Balance).