# Etherscan API - Get all token balances

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, balances

Is there a way with the Etherscan API you can get all the erc20 token balances for a specific address?

As explained [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11710/how-can-i-find-out-the-token-balance-of-some-address), you can see token balances with their web UI (the token tracker dropdown).
Does their API provide equivalent functionality?

As far as I can tell, you can only query for a specific token of which you already have the address. I need functionality equivalent to Ethplorer's API endpoint `getAddressInfo/{address}`.

Comment: did you found a way to do it?

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it using web scraping. You can find my code here: https://github.com/aaronk6/ERC20-MoneyMoney Additionally, I’ve contacted Etherscan support to find out if they plan to add those routes to their API. Let’s see.

Comment: As of July of 2021 is still not possible to do it using Etherscan API. An alternative is to use Moralis web3 platform: https://docs.moralis.io/transactions-and-balances/token-balances

Comment: I wrote something for this. https://gist.github.com/darkerego/dbc915b769b727e9a9cf880af90abe4d

Answer (score 12):

As previously mentioned it doesn't appear possible using etherscan. But it's possible using the (free) ethexplorer.io API.

The format is:

[https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/[YOUR_ADDRESS]?apiKey=freekey](https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/%5BYOUR_ADDRESS%5D?apiKey=freekey)

For example:

https://api.ethplorer.io/getAddressInfo/0x32Be343B94f860124dC4fEe278FDCBD38C102D88?apiKey=freekey

(Note: Must be HTTPS, HTTP will return a 404 error with link to docs, without specifying exactly what's wrong.)

API documentation is here:

https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API

Website:

https://ethplorer.io

Comment: ethplorer has large delay.. unfortunatelly

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible with their current API.

Depending on your project, a workaround could be web scraping. Here’s an example using Lua and xpath:

*Get all contract addresses for which the given ETH address holds tokens:*

```
function requestContractAddressesForEthAddress(ethAddress)

  -- No API method for this (as of Mar 11, 2018), therefore using web scraping

  local connection = Connection()
  local html = HTML(connection:get("https://etherscan.io/address/" .. ethAddress))
  local elements = html:xpath("//ul[@id='balancelist']/li/a")
  local addresses = {}

  elements:each(function (index, element)
    local href = element:attr('href')
    local address = string.match(href, "^%/token%/(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)")
    table.insert(addresses, address)
  end)

  return addresses
end
```

*Get info on a token (name, USD price, divisor to calculate correct amount) for a given contract address:*

```
function requestTokenInfo(contractAddress)

  -- No API method for this (as of Mar 11, 2018), therefore using web scraping

  local connection = Connection()
  local html = HTML(connection:get("https://etherscan.io/token/" .. contractAddress))
  local name = html:xpath("//*[@id='address']"):text()
  local summary = html:xpath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_divSummary']"):text()
  local decimals = tonumber(string.match(summary, "Token Decimals:%s+([%d,]+)"))

  return {
    name = name,
    price = tonumber(string.match(summary, "Value per Token:%s+$([%d%.,]+)")),
    divisor = math.pow(10, decimals)
  }
end
```

**Please be aware that web scraping is considered bad practice. This can break without notice, as it is obviously relying on how the frontend is rendered.**

I’ve contacted Etherscan.io support on Mar 12, 2018 to find out if those API calls are on their roadmap. The answer was that providing paid custom APIs services is not their short-term focus.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with any node, no external API needed, with the help of a smart contract. I just recently wrote a smart contract and library for this, and put it into an NPM package. You can check it out here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-balance-checker

The call looks like this:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
import { getAddressBalances } from 'eth-balance-checker/lib/web3';

const web3 = new Web3(...);
const address = '0x123...';
const tokens = ['0x0', '0x456...'];
getAddressBalances(web3, address, tokens).then(balances => {
  console.log(balances); // { "0x0": "100", "0x456...": "200" }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the defilama free api to get all the token addresses. Then I looped over them with the etherscan free api.

Answer (score 0):

ethexplorer.io is now defunct. Current options I could find for getting all token balances include [Covalent](https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/balances/get-token-balances-for-address/) and [Etherscan](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/tokens#get-address-erc20-token-holding)

There were others providing this functionality and they keep disappearing. Others are launching it now, like [Footprint Analytics](https://docs.footprint.network/reference/get_nft-wallet-balance) (currently only NFTs, moving to all ERC20 as well, from direct communication)