# Which method will return the liquidity list provided by user?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, uniswap, pancakeswap, liquidity-provider

I am new to the DEX development. Am using pancakeswap router contract https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xd99d1c33f9fc3444f8101754abc46c52416550d1

Using ethers.js to call contracts.

**addLiquidityETH** is working to add the liquidity in the DEX. I need to display a list. Which method I need to call in router or in factory contract to display the liquidity added details like below image

[image: Liquidity List]

Need to display the list while loading. We don't have any pairaddress to call `IERC20(pair).balanceOf(address)`. I didnt understand what was the logic behind to display the list by getting pairaddress first and then get the balance

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/#addliquidityeth), the amount of tokens representing the liquidity you have added are returned under the `liquidity` parameter

If it wasn't your first time adding liquidity for the pair, then you can calculate the overall balance by using

`IERC20(pair).balanceOf(your_address);`

Comment: Thanks. Need to display the list while loading. We don't have any pairaddress to call this code. I didnt understand what was the logic behind to display the list by getting pairadress and then get the balance.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood then. If you want to get the list of LP tokens for a given address, then you need to somehow keep track of the event logs like `Transfer`. Some API's like Covalent/Etherscan will do this for you, and you can just then filter them out.

Comment: Thanks @Smye Do you know whether the BSCscan will give these information in BSC?

Comment: I believe so as it is essentially the same as Etherscan - but you will need to double check

Comment: Ok. If we want to find LP-Tokens in Etherscan. We have to call Get a list of "ERC20 - Token Transfer Events" by Address API right?

Comment: Could keep track of all the transfers, but I think an easier way is suggested here:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34335/etherscan-api-get-all-token-balances

Comment: You mean need to keep track of all the transfers. Then only we can able to use etherscan.io API. Pl.Confirm..